# How to connect to a local Redis server from a Docker container?

Tags: docker, redis

I'm trying to connect from inside a Docker container to a local Redis server on my machine. What I did so far:

- Redis is up an running on my machine (can connect to it via *redis-cli*)
- started an interactive Docker container (from the Ubuntu image)
- installed "redis-tool" inside the container
- tried to connect to Redis via redis-cli:
  > `redis-cli -h 172.17.0.3 -p 6379`
  (got the IP address via `ifconfig` inside the container)
- got an error saying "connection refused"

What's the trick I'm not thinking of in order to get a working connection?

I already tried to set "bind 0.0.0.0" in my `redis.conf` but that had no effect. I also tried to forward the port 6379 to 6379 when running the container but I get an error saying the address is already in use.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should not connect to IP address of the container, but IP of the host (one you see on host for Docker bridge). Looking at your question it should be `172.17.0.1`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This didn't work for me as there was not ifconfig entry for the docker bridge. Does this answer apply for a Mac as well?

Comment: @Cheruvim `host.docker.internal` helped me

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

- Get IP of your host machine, e.g. in an *environment variable* `$host_ip`
- Run docker command like:

  ```sh
  docker run -it --add-host redis_server:$host_ip ubuntu bash
  ```

Now from inside container you will be able to reach Redis server via hostname `redis_server` running on your host machine.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this command

"docker run --network=host -p port:port IMAGE"

Not only Redis, All your service you run at your localhost you need on docker you can use with this.

Answer (score -1):

Use **link** between containers.
`docker run -d --name=redis_xyz redis`

`docker run -it --link redis_xyz:redis_local redis_cli_image redis-cli -h redis_local`

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I wasn't looking to run redis inside a container!

Comment: Sorry.
So try inside redis-cli container:
redis-cli -h 0.0.0.0
or
redis-cli -h HostIP.
172.17.0.3 is container IP. Use -h HostIP or -h 0.0.0.0